# Post form Data, but only one has Undefined Index error

Tags: php, forms, post, indexing, undefined

Ive been searching for an answer, with no luck. There is one possible related post, but there is no answer avail.

Im posting form data to itself via the post action. Im then retreiving all the posted values, before sending them into a mysql table.

```
<?php 
require_once 'config.php'; 
    $gemBarcode = $gemSpec = $gemVar = $gemWeigh = $gemShape = $gemCut = $gemCol = $gemBrill = $gemClear = $gemTreat = $gemCertNum = $gemLWarehouse=""; 
    $gemDesc=""; 
    $createdDate = $modifiedDate = $gemChecked =""; 
    $gemW = $gemH = $gemCert =0; 
    $gemlength = 0; 
//if form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
//form actions once submitted (Ie: Check the validity, and if all ok submit to server) - I will complete this later 

    $gemBarcode = $_POST['gemBarcode'];
    $gemSpec = $_POST['gemSpec'];
    $gemVar = $_POST['gemVar'];
    $gemWeigh = $_POST['gemWeigh'];
    $gemShape = $_POST['gemShape'];
    $gemCut = $_POST['gemCut'];
    $gemCol = $_POST['gemCol'];
    $gemBrill = $_POST['gemBrill'];
    $gemClear = $_POST['gemClear'];
    $gemTreat = $_POST['gemTreat'];
    $gemCertNum = $_POST['gemCertNum'];
    $gemLWarehouse=  $_POST['gemLWarehouse'];
    $gemDesc =  $_POST['gemDesc'];
    $createdDate = date("Y-m-d"); 
    $modifiedDate = date("Y-m-d"); 
    $gemChecked = date("Y-m-d"); 
    $gemW = $_POST['gemW'];
    $gemH = $_POST['gemH'];
    $gemlength = $_POST['gemlength']; 
    $gemCert = $_POST['gemCert'];

// $sqlstatement=$mysqli->prepare();

$sql = "INSERT INTO stockitems (gemBarcode, gemSpec, gemVar, gemWeigh, gemShape, gemCut, gemClear, gemW, gemH, gemL, gemCol, gemBrill, gemTreat, gemCert, gemCertNum, gemLWarehouse, createdDate, modifiedDate, gemChecked, gemDesc) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"; 

    if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql)){
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssdddsssissssss",$Para_gemBarcode, $Para_gemSpec, $Para_gemVar, $Para_gemWeigh, $Para_gemShape, $Para_gemCut, $Para_gemClear, $Para_gemW, $Para_gemH, $Para_gemLen, $Para_gemCol, $Para_gemBrill, $Para_gemTreat, $Para_gemCert, $Para_gemCertNum, $Para_gemLWarehouse, $Para_createdDate, $Para_modifiedDate, $Para_gemChecked, $Para_gemDesc);
        $Para_gemBarcode = $gemBarcode; 
        $Para_gemSpec = $gemSpec;
        $Para_gemVar = $gemVar; 
        $Para_gemWeigh = $gemWeigh;
        $Para_gemShape = $gemShape; 
        $Para_gemCut = $gemCut;
        $Para_gemCol = $gemCol; 
        $Para_gemBrill = $gemBrill;
        $Para_gemClear = $gemClear;
        $Para_gemTreat = $gemTreat; 
        $Para_gemCertNum = $gemCertNum; 
        $Para_gemLWarehouse =$gemLWarehouse;
        $Para_gemDesc = $gemDesc;
        $Para_createdDate = $createdDate; 
        $Para_modifiedDate = $modifiedDate; 
        $Para_gemChecked = $gemChecked; 
        $Para_gemW = $gemW; 
        $Para_gemH = $gemH; 
        $Para_gemLen = $gemlength; 
        $Para_gemCert  = $gemCert; 

        if ($stmt->execute()){
            echo "Successfully executed <br>"; 
            //WILL REDIRECT
        } else {
            echo "Execution Failed: <br> ".$mysqli->errno.": ".$mysqli->error; 
        }

    }
    //$stmt->close(); - any idea why this is throwing an error? 
    $mysqli->close(); 

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="eng"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add New Gemstone</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<style type="text/css"> 
    * { font-family: "arial"; }
    .wrapper {
        width: 90%; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body> 

    <div class="wrapper"> 
        <form class='form-inline' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">

            <div class='row'> 
                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemBarcode'>Barcode</label>
                <input type='number' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemBarcode' placeholder='Barcode' required  value='<?php echo $gemBarcode;?>'> 
            </div>  

            <div class='row'>
                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemSpec'>Species</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemSpec' placeholder='Species'   value='<?php echo $gemSpec;?>'> 
                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemVar'>Variant</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control com-md-3' name='gemVar' placeholder='Variant'   value='<?php echo $gemVar;?>'>
            </div>  

            <div class='row'>
                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemWeigh'>Weight</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemWeigh' placeholder='Gem Weight (ct/g)'   value='<?php echo $gemWeigh;?>'>

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemShape'>Shape</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemShape' placeholder='Shape'   value='<?php echo $gemShape;?>'> 

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemCut'>Cut</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemCut' placeholder='Cut'   value='<?php echo $gemCut;?>'> 
            </div>  
            <div class='row'>
                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemW'>Width</label>
                <input type='number' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemW' placeholder='Width (mm)' step='Any'  value='<?php echo $gemW;?>'> 

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemH'>Height</label>
                <input type='number' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemH' placeholder='Height (mm)' step='any'  value='<?php echo $gemH;?>'>

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemlength'>Length</label> 
                <input type='number' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemlength' placeholder='Length (mm)' step='any' value='<?php echo $gemlength; ?>'> 
            </div>  
            <div class='row'>
                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemCol'>Colour</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemCol' placeholder='Colour'   value='<?php echo $gemCol;?>'> 

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemBrill'>Brilliance</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemBrill' placeholder='Brilliance'   value='<?php echo $gemBrill;?>'>

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemClear'>Clarity</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemClear' placeholder='Clarity'   value='<?php echo $gemClear;?>'> 
            </div>  
            <div class='row'>
                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemTreat'>Enhancement</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemTreat' placeholder='Enhanced'   value='<?php echo $gemTreat;?>'>

                <div class='col'>
                    <label class='col-md-2' for='gemCert'>Certified</label>
                    <select class='form-control col-md-2' style='width=auto !important;' name='gemCert'> 
                        <option></option>
                        <option value=1>Yes</option>
                        <option value=2>No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemCertNum'>Certificate Number</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemCertNum' placeholder='Certificate Number'   value='<?php echo $gemCertNum;?>'> 
            </div>  

            <div class='row'>
                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemLWarehouse'>Warehouse</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemLWarehouse' placeholder='Gem Location'   value='<?php echo $gemLWarehouse;?>'>

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemDesc'>Description</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-7' name='gemDesc' placeholder=''   value='<?php echo $gemDesc;?>'> 
            </div>  

            <div class='row'>
                <label class='col-md-2' for='createdDate'>Created</label>
                <input type='date' class='form-control col-md-2' name='createdDate' placeholder='Date Loaded'   value='<?php echo $createdDate;?>'>

                <label class='col-md-2' for='modifiedDate'>Modified</label>
                <input type='date' class='form-control col-md-2' name='modifiedDate' placeholder='Date last Changed'   value='<?php echo $modifiedDate;?>'>

                <label class='col-md-2' for='gemChecked'>Checked</label>
                <input type='date' class='form-control col-md-2' name='gemChecked' placeholder='Date last Checked'   value='<?php echo $gemChecked;?>'> 
            </div>
            <div class='row'> 
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='submit'>
                <a href='index.php' class='btn btn-defaul'>Cancel</a>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Notes: - Please excuse the spelling - dyslexia. I had a lot of trouble with the word length, (spelling it lenght at times) but i redone these and they are all consistent. Also note: Colour is spelt right here in South Africa, Color in USA.

EDIT: The error is  picked up on this line: 
    $gemlength = $_POST['gemlength']; 
Its not a problem with my spelling, I've checked and rechecked.

Comment: The error message should tell you which line the error happened on, which in turn should point you exactly to what you spelt wrong. All you then need to do is compare a two words. If you have trouble memorizing spellings, copy and paste them into an empty editor window underneath each other, the difference should become very apparent.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention where the error was. Its not a spelling thing, i do the copy and paste thing constantly to prevent errors. Ive edited the post with the error details.

Comment: It maybe referring to empty post key. try adding a condition when you are declaring your post variables like this `$gemW = (isset($_POST['gemW'])) ? $_POST['gemW'] : "";`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but all of a sudden it started to work again, and I hadnt changed anything. Oh well, thanks anyway!